# How Can I compare date of main report with a date of subreport to get data?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, subreports

I have a main report in   of visual studio 2010.

It is group  RecipeDate and inside its header there is a subreport.
In subreport there is a IssueDate.
I want to s all the issuance in the subreport issued right after/on RecipeDate but before the  RecipeDate.

For Example:

**If I have a Recipe prepared on 18/11/2013**

**and started issuing from the  day i.e 19/11/2013**

**and the next Recipe is prepared on 25/11/2013.**

**so I want to show all the issuance between 18/11/2013 till 25/11/2013**

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Link the `RecipeDate`of main report with the `IssueDate` of the sub report using main report links and in subreport `Record Selection formula` add a condition like

```
?RecipeDate=?IssueDate
```

Comment: I am trying something like this                                    if (({usp_rptDateWiseSolution.IssueDate})>=({usp_rptDateWiseSolution.RecipeDate}))
AND ((Previous({usp_rptDateWiseSolution.RecipeDate}))<(Next({usp_rptDateWiseSolution.RecipeDate})))
then
true

Comment: On linking as you said I am seeing an empty subreports

Comment: I am not familiar with coding but I can tell you how can you link in tool... go to placed sub report and right click and go to `Change subreport links`

Comment: Siva Its a Record Selection Formula

Comment: Try this `if (({usp_rptDateWiseSolution.RecipeDate})>= <<date Database Filed>> and {usp_rptDateWiseSolution.IssueDate}<=<<Date Databae field>>`

Comment: <Date Database field> ?

Comment: Date filed from database where you are firing the query

Comment: empty records in subreport :(

Comment: Can you paste the query here?

Comment: I've done it :) Thankyou so much for giving me the idea. Without your idea it wasn't possible.

Comment: siva one more thing i want to ask can we talk ?

Comment: I don't like discussing in personal  mails you can ask what ever you want here..So that I can reply.

Comment: Now I am having an issue in summarizing the record in subreport. Because I've applied the conditional formula in suppress section so in order to sum the record it is counting all the record. I tried using the running total but not working for me

Comment: this is my conditional formula in supress section of IssueQty `if({usp_rptDateWiseSolution.IssueDate}>={@SharedRecipeDate2} and {usp_rptDateWiseSolution.IssueDate}<{@NextSharedRecipeDate2} AND {usp_rptDateWiseSolution.IssueQty}>0)
then false
else true`

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem what is the datatype of the field you are summing

Comment: Yeah really.. it is decimal

Comment: I suppose though the value is decimal datatype may be varchar `Just Guess`, Otherwise it should sum without any problem